# How should I go about monitoring the I/O of a serial port if I have a device which takes in two serial ports?

Tags: c#, .net-micro-framework

I have a NetMF application, which uses two serial ports which communicate with one another. How should I 'debug' this as to see  exactly what is being sent to and from both serial ports at the same time?

one the 'com1' side:

```
 static SerialPort comPort;
comPort = new SerialPort("COM1",9600,Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);
comPort.ReadTimeout = 1000; comPort.WriteTimeout = 1000;
comPort.Open();//Opens comPort Successfully
```

but I am sending data in hex, but the `bytesToRead` and `bytesToWrite` are always 0?

Comment: i have tried portmon one both ends, and get a read/write on one side, but i can't seem to get any response on the other side of the board.

Comment: So if portmon is showing activity at one end but not the other that indicates a connectivity problem. Are the two ports properly connected? Is your serial cable wiring correct?

Comment: Yes, i've already checked that. It's somewhere in the communication between this port on the device (wired into com1 on the board) and the other (which is connected to the PC's com1). the other side of the board (com3) works perfectly when i sniff it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a service like portmon or serial sniffer - these will access the serial port and 'listen' to them.

Comment: i've just used serial sniffer, and it seems to have figured out my problem. It was the way the data needed to be sent through. Thanks!